# Getting "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error?

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, wkwebview

I am creating a simple web viewer using WKWebView and the Swift language. Here is my code.

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

@NSApplicationMain class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : NSView! = nil
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        var webView: WKWebView

        webView = WKWebView() //Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x20)
        var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(req)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

}
```

I'm now getting a "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error on the `webView = WKWebView()` line when I try to run the application. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If that's it's all your code, than I'd say you're missing to instantiate the `WKWebView`. Put a breakpoint on the `self.webView!.loadRequest(req)` line and check whether it's nil or not.

I've never worked with `WKWebView`, but I think that you need a view controller. Maybe this blog post can help you: [Getting started with WKWebView using Swift in iOS 8](http://www.kinderas.com/technology/2014/6/7/getting-started-with-wkwebview-using-swift-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialise your WKWebView

```
var webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480))
var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
webView.loadRequest(req)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've modified my code (see edited code above) but i'm now getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the initialise line?

Comment: @user1741348 How about trying 
var webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480))

Answer (score 0):

I get this error whenever I try to use a brand new minimal class as a delegate. For example:

`class MyDelegate: NSObject, UIWebViewDelegate { /* ... */ }`

This does not happen when I try to use the default ViewController as a delegate. For example:

`class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate { /* ... */ }`

I would suggest using the ViewController as a delegate until we get to the bottom of this.