# Cocoa error beep | performKeyEquivalent

Tags: cocoa, beep

I have a Cocoa/swift application that creates a minimal web view using WKWebView (see code below).

When I run the app the sample web page (currently www.google.com) loads correctly, however if I try to use keyUp and keyDown methods or try to copy and paste text I get the system error sound/ding/beep.

So i have created a performKeyEquivalent function:

```
func performKeyEquivalent(theEvent: NSEvent) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

but I dont think I have implemented it correctly. I'm new to xcode and swift.

See below the complete code. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
import Cocoa import WebKit import AppKit

@NSApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var customView: NSView!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
        var theWebView:WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: customView.bounds)
        customView.addSubview(theWebView)
        theWebView.autoresizingMask = NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewWidthSizable | NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewHeightSizable   
        theWebView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func performKeyEquivalent(theEvent: NSEvent) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasted about an hour trying to track down a solution to your problem but I'm hitting the same crash you were hitting in your [earlier EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253005/getting-thread-1exc-bad-access-error), when simply trying to programatically create a "`WKWebView`" in Swift using your above code. How did you ever solve that?  In the mean time, I recommend creating a "`NSWindowController`" and moving your "`WKWebView`" code to there.

Comment: I never did manage to solve the EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash issue in the previous code posted, however I did find another solution on https://tetontech.wordpress.com/tag/webview/ which I modified slightly to work on Cocoa. I'm new to Xcode and swift, how do you create a "NSWindowController" ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get rid of the Error Beep? I'm having the same problem.